# Single word for (shrugging) hands action

Tags: gestures

If you want to convey "What now?" or "I don't know what to do", you might lift your hands up and outwards. Is there a word or phrase for this action and intent? Closest I can think of is 'She shrugged her hands' but OED only lists shrug (as a gesture) as applying to the shoulders.

I've tried a reverse dictionary search and searched on this SE but cannot find an answer to this exact question.

Comment: I thought about this for a minute, but ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ .

Comment: ¯|_(ツ)_/¯ fantastic and fun tactic!

Comment: 'throwing up one's hands in frustration?

Comment: That would fit, @Spagirl, thanks (as I do the same at not thinking of that). I'll wait a little to see if anyone can come up with a shorter phrase.

Comment: See also what [Darwin](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_expression_of_the_emotions_in_man_an/6eAyAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=shrugged+shoulders+and+hands&pg=PA267&printsec=frontcover) has to say about shrugging with shoulders/hands.  (pp.265-271)

Answer (score 1):

You can say that she *threw up her hands*.

> **throw up one's hands**
>   Raise both hands in the air as an indication of one's exasperation.
>   ‘Dickens threw up his hands in impatience’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/throw_up_one's_hands)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could describe it as *she **splayed** her hands*, as in

> “What's the matter, Nick?”<sup>1</sup> She blew out her breath, splayed her hands in front of her. She took a step closer to him and said, “I know what's going. I know." ([Catherine Coulter, *The Eleventh Hour*, 2002](https://books.google.com/books?id=EaGIAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT65&dq=%22She%20blew%20out%20her%20breath%2C%20splayed%20her%20hands%20in%20front%20of%20her.%22&pg=PT65#v=onepage&q=%22She%20blew%20out%20her%20breath,%20splayed%20her%20hands%20in%20front%20of%20her.%22&f=false))
>
> She splayed her hands in exasperation. “What are you talking about?" ([Michael A. Martin, *Fallen Gods*, 2012](https://books.google.com/books?id=x-mTrVdP53cC&lpg=PT269&dq=%22splayed%20her%20hands%20in%22&pg=PT269#v=onepage&q=%22splayed%20her%20hands%20in%22&f=false))
>
> Quinn shrugged his shoulder and splayed his hands, “I guess that came out wrong." ([Robin Wood, *Murder She Spoke*, 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=qOHqAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA31&dq=%22splayed%20his%20hands%22&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q=%22splayed%20his%20hands%22&f=false))

Of course *splaying* is just *spreading*, so one can *splay one's hands **on*** something, etc., which changes the meaning of the phrase, but without such specificity I picture a gesture something like [this](http://static1.fjcdn.com/thumbnails/comments/Dude+i+can+t+draw+that+well+and+i+haven+t+_b5ee466145f885b095f8ef584a0af009.jpg).

---

<sup>1</sup> Incidentally, I'm sure it's a spurious correlation, but the name Nick and variations thereof co-occurred with this phrase in my search results to a startling degree.

Answer (score 1):

I delved into the good old classics a little and could find some interesting formulae:

- "I have never entered on it," said Mrs Cadwallader, opening her hands. (Elliot);
- "There, again!" said I, stopping before Herbert, with my open hands held out, as if they contained the desperation of the case. (Dickens);
- "Ah, so do I, George," the old lady returns, shaking her head and parting her folded hands. (Dickens);
- So we just sit here flapping away helplessly. (from "Polisse" movie).

I also stumbled across "to do big arms", but it's to your judgement whether to implement this phrase as an equivalent to "What now?"/"I don't know what to do".

Answer (score 0):

Throwing your hands up is different from the palms-up shrug.

'Throwing your hands up' is done in a angry or frustrated fashion, while palms-up shrug is done when you don't have the answer or used as a questioning or sarcastic posture (like 'what else could I have done?')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).